# Why are grails sources not in the /src folder?

Tags: grails

A fresh created grails app contains the `grails-app` folder right beside the `src` folder. The `grails-app` folder contains all sources of the Grails application.

Why is this folder not inside the `src` folder?

Can it moved somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it can not and should not be moved. The `src` folder is different than the `grails-app` folder for a reason. The `grails-app` folder contains the conventional Grails application structure where as `src` is intended to include other Groovy and Java sources that don't intentionally fall into the standard convention of a Grails application (e.g. TagLib, Domain class, Controller, Service, GSP, js/css asset, etc.)

Comment: Thanx for your answer! I do understand that the `grails.app` folder is special, but IMHO, it could also be located in `src/grails-app` right besides `src/main/groovy` `src/test`. I still see no reason why not...

Comment: If you were to move it you would be breaking the convention of a Grails project structure, which would make your project more difficult for someone else to understand and would require you to re-tool all the Grails scripts/code to understand your new directory structure. Seems like a lot of work for no obvious benefits. Trust the Grails dev team and their decades of experience, and enjoy the convention over configuration nature of Grails! Just my humble opinion.

Comment: "I still see no reason why not" - There is not really a reason that we couldn't have implemented it that way, but we didn't.  Had it been implemented that way, it might be reasonable to ask why not move the `grails-app/` folder out of `src/` and to the top level since it is a special kind of source directory.  None of that really matters.  The way it is implemented isn't going to change.

Comment: thanx! That was the answer I was looking for!